# Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service is masked

Tags: gunicorn, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I am trying to deploy django web application on alibabacloud everything seems to be working perfectly(running gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 project_name.wsgi on virtual environment)

Then after deactivating the virtual environment and setting up

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=admin
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/admin/project_name
ExecStart=/home/admin/project_name/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind 
unix:/home/admin/project_name/project_name.sock project_name.wsgi:application
```

in `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`
then running `sudo systemctl start gunicorn` I keep getting the error

```
Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service is masked.
```

Please how can I fix this?

I have tried `systemctl unmask gunicorn.socket` but it keeps showing me the error

```
Unit gunicorn.socket does not exist, proceeding anyway.
Failed to unmask unit: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided 
by any .service files
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `systemctl unmask gunicorn.service`?

Comment: Thanks @sykez the error is shown because of sudo privilege it suppose to be `sudo systemctl unmask gunicorn.socket`